# php to python inter-process communication with large data by json

Tags: php, python, json, interprocess

my php code:

```
<?php
$data = array('as', 'df', 'gh');
$result=shell_exec("start test.py ".escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
?>
```

test.py code:

```
import sys
import json
try:
    print json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "ERROR"
print
raw_input()
```

it's failing to try and showing ERROR.
while if change my python code to this:

```
import sys
try:
    data=sys.argv[1]
except:
    print "ERROR"
print data,
raw_input()
```

i'm getting the output as: `[ as , df , gh ]`

as i'm passing a json encoded data, i should be able to decode it with python's json.loads() method. but why it's not working?

Comment: Can you post the output from your PHP code? In other words, print out the exact string that's being passed to the shell.

Comment: with `echo escapeshellarg(json_encode($data));` i'm getting output `"[ as , df , gh ]"`

Comment: That's not valid json. at bare minimum it should be `["af","df","gh"]` after json_encode, and `'["af","df","gh"]'` after escapeshellarg

Comment: @MarcB what's the solution. i'm just calling library functions, nothing else. i want to send a associative array created by a html form and pass it to python. but with json encoding not working what can i do?

Comment: check into why your json_encode is screwing up so badly. if that's really what yours is producing, you've got a majorly buggy install.

Comment: @MarcB with deleting `escapeshellarg` and writing just `echo json_encode($data);` i'm getting a output `{"1":"as","2":"df","3":"gh"}` and in python `{1:as,2:df,3:gh}` for `$data = array("1"=>"as","2"=>"df","3"=>"gh");`

Comment: ok. so it's creating a JS object (`{}`) instead of an array (`[]`). Probably because you're quoting your array keys in the original array definition, so that json_encode sees their internal type as strings, meaning it HAS to produce an object.

Comment: @MarcB that's how i've to pass an associative array and in python, convert it to an dictionary. instead of keys like `1,2,3` i'll have `"name", "mail"` etc as keys. i guess, problem is with `escapeshellarg()` in windows. i've read some issues.

Comment: gotcha. but the shellarg stuff won't matter to python, any escaping done by the shell will only be relevant to the shell, and the escapes/quotes will be gone when the data gets into python.

Comment: @MarcB don't know what is the problem. with `shell_exec("start test.py ".json_encode(json_encode($data)));` i'm receiving in python a string `{"1":"as","2":"df","3":"gh"}` for `$data = array('1' => "as",'2' => "df",'3' => "gh");` but not being able to convert that string to a dictionary with ast.literal_eval(). it's producing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know how it's working. but able to tune the program according to what i want.

php code:

```
<?php
$data = array('1'=>"as",'2'=>"df",'3'=>"gh");
$result=shell_exec("start test.py ".json_encode(json_encode($data)));
?>
```

test.py:

```
import sys
import json

try:
    data=sys.argv[1]
except:
    print "ERROR"

print data
dit=json.loads(data)
print dit
print dit['1']
raw_input()
```

and got the output as required:

```
{"1":"as","2":"df","3":"gh"}
{u'1': u'as', u'3': u'gh', u'2': u'df'}
as
```

someone having a good knowledge in these pls explain.

Comment: Yeap. Please explain. But thanks for the tips.it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following:

> On Windows, escapeshellarg() removes percent signs, replaces double
>   quotes with spaces and adds double quotes around the string.

-> https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

I'd recommend using **addslashes(...)**

```
exec("test.py " . addslashes(json_encode($json)) . " 2>&1", $output, $exit_code);
```